# How to get data from two tables by using Inner queries or inner join

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am new to sql queries and learning now.. I have to execute one query which is like this.. there are two tables A and B. I want all data from A  table and A table but there one column Id, this is is in both table, whenever this id matches in both the table, then that data I have to display. 
For example :

Table A has following columns

```
Id    Date       Time       Status
XX    12/1/15    4:00       true
YY    12/1/15    5:00       true
ZZ    12/1/15    6:00       true
AA    12/1/15    7:00       true
```

Table B has following data

```
Id    Name       Address       City
BB    asdf       qwer          IN
CC    ascd       qwer          UN
DD    asdag      qwer          RA
ZZ    asear      qwer          US
```

By seeing above table, `Id` value `ZZ` is matching with both table, I need both table same column data like from table A :

```
ZZ     12/1/15    6:00       true
```

and from table B

```
ZZ     asear      qwer       US
```

Till now I am trying following queries But there is not luck.

```
1. SELECT * FROM B INNER JOIN A ON B.Id = A.Id 
2. SELECT * FROM B WHERE LeadID IN 
   (SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.Id=B.Id
```

I am getting all the datas from B table.

EDIT:
Output for 1st query is all column from table `B` and table `A`. I am thins B.id = A.id is working or not..

Please anybody help me

Comment: Seems is a simply     SELECT * FROM B INNER JOIN A ON B.ID = A.ID

Comment: Show the desired output for this example data.

Comment: @CL Pls check I edited question

Comment: @scaisEdge I am also thinking same But the problem is getting all column values from both table.

Comment: Do not *describe* the desired output; *show* it.

Comment: @CL.I am running those queries in directly device only.. Cant able to show, sorry sir..

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * from B INNER JOIN A ON B.id=A.id;` would work

Else explicitly specify the fields

```
SELECT B.name, B.address, B.city, A.date, A.time, A.status 
from B INNER JOIN A ON B.id=A.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

By your comment try

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM B INNER JOIN A ON B.ID = A.ID;
```

or

```
SELECT B.name, B.address, B.city, A.date, A.time, A.status 
from B INNER JOIN A ON B.id=A.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*,b.* from tableA as a
inner join tableB as b
on a.Id == b.Id
```

Above query will return tableA and tableB data by using Id

Comment: Wat output u will get here?? Same output only I am getting with this query

Comment: It will return all data if id match in both tables a and b

Comment: will it compare each id of B table with A table?? I got out but one column is coming wrong, I have total 6 cloumns in both table, all of them 5 columns are matching with each other, so I have to get 5 length data right?? But I am getting 6 number of length data and first column is repeating with not matched column..

Comment: yes it should compare each id of tableA and tableB. Instead of column you mean row/record?

Comment: can you share snapshot of db table? @user3107283

Answer (score 0):

SELECT a.*,b.* from A as a inner join B as b where a.ID=b.ID;

This is used to get the data from table A matches with Table B